# Query router for list of multicast sources

Tags: multicast, pim

Is it possible to query a router to return a list multicast sources it has registered, via a protocol?

For example, I want to know what multicast sources are available on a router but I don't have control over that router.

My thought was a PIM query or spoofing as another router via PIM message may allow me to recieve the multicast table. Is this possible, or am  I going down the wrong path?

Comment: Just playing around, I've found if I send out a PIMv2 Hello message, the router will start forwarding ALL multicast traffic to me... not quite what I want but at least it shows the concept *could* work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have control over the router that you are trying to query it is going to be difficult to do this.

By spoofing a PIM query or join, the router isn't going to tell you what its has in its routing table, it will start forwarding you the data and you'll be able to see all the sources.  So if you don't have any control over the router this maybe your only option.

Remember that in multicast routing all the routing decisions are made by that one router alone, based on the routers unicast routing table.  So there isn't really a mechanism to learn someone else multicast routing table.

There are SNMP MIBs for querying the mroute table, but that again would require some level of control over the router you wish to query. http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.83.1.1.2.1#oidContent

Another method, if you had control over the router, is to use MSDP.  http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfmsdp.html

Multicast Source Discovery Protocol will allow RPs in a network to share the sources for multicast groups with each other.  However, you need to setup a MSDP peer between each RP to do so.

Comment: Thanks this is great info and very detailed. Assuming the PIM spoof, is there a good way to get the router to stop sending the multicast traffic? Setting PIM timeout to 0 (a goodbye) had no effect.

Comment: Send a PIM prune message, this will tell the upstream router you no longer want the data in the message.